# liferea: change text size using liferea.css

Tags: fonts, user-interface, css

I have downloaded sample `css` file: https://github.com/lwindolf/liferea/blob/master/css/liferea.css

and I am trying to change the font size of:

1. the feed name in the left pane (feed list)
2. the headline in the top right pane (headline)

see red markings on attached screenshot:
[image]

so far, all changes I have tried in `liferea.css` only affect the bottom right pane, which displays the actual page content

How can I change the text size in liferea of the feed list, and the headline?

I have found similar questions on the liferea mailing list, but they only point to editing the `liferea.css` file, without explaining which property has to be changed:

https://sourceforge.net/p/liferea/mailman/message/31652848/

I am using `liferea 1.12.6` on Debian 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferea is not an Electron app.  You cannot style its interface with CSS, because they are not made with HTML.  (Imagine that!  One would have thought the lower memory consumption might have clued you in.)

Well, this is not exactly true.  GTK 3 supports styling with a language sufficiently similar to CSS (and even called ‘CSS’ in many places in the documentation) that you would be forgiven for thinking it actually is CSS; but it doesn’t actually style an HTML or even XML DOM tree.  GTK 3 allows installing per-user custom styles by putting them in `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.  With GTK 3.24, the following should affect font sizes in both panels after restarting Liferea:

```css
treeview {
    font-size: 14pt;
}

treeview#itemlist {
    font-size: 18pt;
}
```

However, those styles will be applied to every GTK 3 app on your system; they are not restricted to Liferea only.  You should expect every single tree view in every application to be affected by the first rule, and possibly by the second rule.  Perhaps there is a way to load a GTK ‘CSS’ style just for a single application, but it would be considerably more involved.

If you ask me, better just set font sizes in GTK settings globally.

Comment: thank you, that works. Can you please explain how you found the names of the properties, ie `treeview#itemlist` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be quite difficult to solve for anyone who doesn't use **Liferea** but I will make a few educated guesses based on the provided CSS.

In the provided [CSS file](https://github.com/lwindolf/liferea/blob/master/css/liferea.css), on **line 127**, this should change the font in the top right panel:

```
table.itemhead * a.itemhead {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#GTK-COLOR-TEXT;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: <Add your font here>
}
```

In regards to the font in the **left panel**, I find it very difficult to find which css is related to it. Maybe if you inspect the element and upload a screenshot while hovering over the DOM so I can see the class name, I would be able to help you more.

So far the only thing that comes to mind is changing this on **line 64**:

```
a {
    color: #GTK-COLOR-NORMAL-LINK;
    font-family: <Add your font here>

}
```

However at the beginning of the file it says:

```
   No style definition should set absolute font sizes,
   font families or line heigth and spacing. This is to allow a GNOME
   preference controlled default font size.
```

So maybe you should try to change the font through your Linux theme, rather the css code?

Comment: thank you, but but these suggested changes do not seem to have any effect

Comment: @400theCat can you inspect the element and hover your cursor over the feed name on the left panel? If you upload the screenshot, I might have better idea of the classes being used.

Comment: I don't know how to "inspect element and hover over DOM". I think in a browser that would be done by entering the developr mode, but how do I do it in liferea?